# Can I add the post featured image to a specific RSS feed?

Tags: php, rss, feed

I'm currently using the following code:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px;' ) ) . '</div>' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

Which does work, but  I'm running a few MailChimp RSS emails campaigns and am needing one RSS feed to show the featured image (articles feed) and one where I don't want to show the featured image.

My thought is to do this by category, possibly?

Let me know if more clarification is needed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPBeginner has a nice article ["
How to Create Custom RSS Feeds in WordPress"](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/) that addresses this from a manageable perspective.

They cover creating custom feeds, and using theme templates to customize what your feeds publish.

Take a look.